# Create new file with duplicities of a file

Tags: csv, awk, grep, solaris

I have the command below which extracts rows that are duplicates based on their second column (`file.csv` is comma-separated):

```
awk -F',' '{print $2}' file.csv | sort | uniq -d | grep -F -f - file.csv >file.bad
```

But on Solaris, this command doesn't work because of the `-F` parameter of the `grep` command is not supported.

Example of lines in the original file:

```
"A","TEST","Other","TEST",...  
"A","TEST2","Other A","TEST2",...  
"A","TEST","Other B","TEST",...
```

Example of lines in the new file:

```
"A","TEST","Other","TEST",...  
"A","TEST","Other B","TEST",...
```

Comment: `-F` is for fixed strings as opposed to regular expressions.  Field 2 in your sample file, however, does not show any regex-active characters.  Are you sure that you need `-F`?

Comment: can you show input vs desired output ?

Comment: If I remove the `-F` parameter, the command doesn't work either. Added the example of the new file

Comment: _"doesn't work either"_  Vague statements like that are not useful.   What does "doesn't work" mean?  Did the command generate error messages? If so, what were they?  If it didn't, then how did the output file differ from what you wanted?  Please be clear and specific.

Comment: sorry, if I remove the parameter, the command don't do anything and don't get any error

Comment: What does "don't do anything" mean?  Does it mean that the output file, `file.bad` is empty?  Or, is it unchanged from what it was before?  Or, what?

Comment: @John1024 Your 1st comment: That's just precisely why he needs `-F`, so that nothing in column 2 is interpreted as a regular expression (this is just test data after all, the real thing might be a lot different).

Comment: @Kusalananda If the pattern has __no__ regex-active characters, what do you expect to be different between using `-F` and not using `-F`?

Comment: @John1024 The test data hasn't, his real data might include dots and other characters that may be problematic without -F.

Comment: @Kusalananda I asked the OP about his real data but I didn't get an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cat sample.csv

```
"A","TEST","Other","TEST",...
"A","TEST2","Other A","TEST2",...
"A","TEST","Other B","TEST",...
```

run below:

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$2]++;next} (a[$2]>1)' sample.csv sample.csv > new_file.csv
```

content of new_file.csv

```
"A","TEST","Other","TEST",...
"A","TEST","Other B","TEST",...
```

What I did is it reads sample 2 times.  The first time store 2nd field in an array, and then the 2nd time check if 2nd field occurrence time is more than once, we print out the line.

- NR==FNR{a[$2]++;next} 
  store 2nd field in array `a` and then go next record/line
- (a[$2]>1) when the 2nd time read sample.csv file, checks the array whether 2nd field occurrence more than once, if 2nd field has duplicates, print out the line

Comment: I try this command and get the error bellow:
  
`awk: record "A"...' has too many fields`

Comment: @Matengo  how many fields in your file?  replace awk with gawk, it doesnt have artificial limits

Comment: @haifzhan +1.  By the way, the native Sun/Solaris awk is notoriously bug-filled.  Sometimes  `nawk` can be used, or
better yet, the GNU versions that might be found at `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk`  or `/usr/xpg6/bin/awk`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `/usr/xpg4/bin/grep` explicitly in you pipeline instead of plain `grep` (which probably picks it up from `/usr/bin/grep`).

The `/usr/bin/grep` on Solaris does not support the `-F` option (nor the `-f` option to read patterns from a file), but `/usr/xpg4/bin/grep` does, according to [Oracle's documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/816-5165/grep-1.html). You might even want to put `/usr/xpg4/bin` at the front of your `$PATH` to avoid this problem in the future.  I'm no Solaris user though, so I don't know whether this is a reasonable thing to do.

Additionally, the `-f` flag of `/usr/xpg4/bin/grep` takes a file name. I'm not certain it understands `-` as standard input.

To force reading from standard input, replace `-` with `/dev/stdin`.

You pipeline now looks like this:

```
awk -F',' '{print $2}' file.csv | sort | uniq -d | /usr/xpg4/bin/grep -F -f /dev/stdin file.csv >file.bad
```

Comment: I try this, but don't generate the new file and don't get any error message

Comment: @Matengo Run your pipeline again, but delete *everything* after `uniq -d`. See if you get the expected output from `uniq` (should be just one line with the text `"TEST"`). If not, you have either the wrong data in you in-file, or there is something else going wrong. If it looks correct, put the end of the pipeline back in, but replace `-f -` with `-f /dev/stdin`.

Comment: @Matengo I'm *really* surprised that you don't get any error messages.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Solaris default `PATH` with which some executed commands end up to be the legacy instead of the POSIX compliant ones. To run a portable script under Solaris (and other Unix like OSes), the simplest approach is add a line at the beginning of your script:

If your script is using `ksh` or `bash`:

```
export PATH="$(getconf PATH):$PATH"
```

If your script is using the legacy `/bin/sh`:

```
PATH="`getconf PATH`:$PATH"; export PATH
```

To get your interactive shell running in compliant mode, you can also add one of these lines to the proper initialization file (`.profile`, `.bash_profile`, ...)

This should fix the issues your command is suffering.